# extract "charsheet" charts, checkboxes status and labels from XLSX using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, ms-word, screen-scraping

I am working on a database that stores data collected from multiple file formats including xlsx, xls, doc, docx, pdf, csv...

These different documents are generated by different systems (~35 different file format) and I'm using python3 to scrape the content and insert it into an SQLite database.

I've tried several python3 packages but I'm still not able to extract charts from "ChartSheet" (an excel sheet containing ONLY a chart, without cells).

[Example of Chart Sheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBDbX.png)

I also have other issues like collecting checkboxes status/labels.

My questions are :

- How can I be able to extract charts from ChartSheet?
- How can I be able to read checkboxes status and labels ?
- Is there a better way (perhaps a unique package?) to scrape content from files (xlsx, xls, doc, docx, pdf)?
  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to process files. I'll describe some of them below:

1. Use python packages. For example, you can use the Open XML SDK for processing open XML documents. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information about that. Just find python packages that act like a wrapper around that SDK. That approach doesn't require MS Office installed on the system.
2. Automate Office applications using the `win32com` package for extracting all the required information. The `win32com.client` package contains a number of modules to provide access to automation objects. This package supports both late and early bindings.

   To use an `IDispatch`-based COM object, use the method `win32com.client.Dispatch()` . This method takes as its first parameter the `ProgID` or `CLSID` of the object you wish to create. If you read the documentation for Microsoft Excel, you’ll find the `ProgID` for Excel is `Excel.Application`, so to create an object that interfaces to Excel, use the following code:

   ```
   import win32com.client
   xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
   ```

   `xl` is now an object representing Excel.

Answer (score 0):

A "ChartSheet" is an MS Office Graphic presentation, and as such it is available to MS Applications as Live Graphics, here we can see a full working preview in Windows Explorer.

[image]

Now that data would be hard, if not impossible for Python to show in a similar Dynamic fashion. Thus the best we may achieve "ACROSS ALL PLATFORMS" to find the data, is look in the file at the composition with Windows native Tar utility and pull the Drawing from the Zip container.

And here we can see Item 1 *"What would this chart look like with data labels"*

[image]

Answer you can untar the file

```
Desktop>tar -xf chart.xlsx "xl/drawings/drawing1.xml"

Desktop>find "What" xl/drawings/drawing1.xml
```

[image]

If you want the graphic aspects you need to print to a graphic Format such as PDF which Excel or LibreOffice can do via scripts, however beware Libre-Office may have problems with Excel files, so here we see extra data carried across as a white layer. (Highlighted in  pale blue)

[image]

Comment: I've added an example of one of my ChartSheet.
Based on the xml file, these type of charts are stored by their values. 
The only way to export as image is to recreate the chart with python (plotlib for ex)?